# How to view multiple consoles in an Xcode workspace?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, console, workspace

I have a client program and a server program (both written in C) in the same Xcode 4.4.1 workspace.  I'm only able to view the console output for the server program. How can I open another console to view the client output?

In the meantime, I've removed both projects from the workspace so they each have their own console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open multiple windows of Xcode and set up each one differently. I recommend opening a new window and hiding everything except the console.